# Send image to php script using Form

Tags: php

hi i want to save image to mysql using php script and form html but in this code i see that the image is not sent to php can you help me please i am beginer in php.

Form.html

```html
<form action="upload_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</p>
</form>
<b> 
<a href="upd.php">Afficher la premiere image de la base de donnes </a>
</b>
```

php script :

```html
<?php
 echo ini_get( 'file_uploads' );
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane");
  if ($con->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
  }
  $img = $_POST['photo'];
  if($img!=null){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)";
  
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
  
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$img);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  
  $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  
  if($check == 1){
   echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Error Uploading Image";
  }
  
  }else{
  echo "image not found";
   }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
  echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

Why is the image not sent to script ? i got always image not found in php.

Comment: Is your code, entering the If condition?

Answer (score 3):

The right way to access to **file** element by `POST` method is not `$img = $_POST['photo']`. You should use `$_FILE` var, for example `$img = $_FILE['photo']['name']` to get the name of file.

There are some different info you can get from `$_FILE` var:

`$_FILES['photo']['name']`
The original name of the file on the client machine.

`$_FILES['photo']['type']`
The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

`$_FILES['photo']['size']`
The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

`$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']`
The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

`$_FILES['photo']['error']`
The error code associated with this file upload.

Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

**Pay attention:** If you need to store the image in DB you need to convert file in binary data and store in DB as `BLOB` type.
Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

As alternative, a good way is to store the file in a folder on your host and save the path in a DB.

Comment: yea , i want to store image to db , but first i have to get the image from the Form.html using POST method, and then save it , what changes to make in my script to do this ?

Comment: i found it i edit my answer, and now i want a script that allows me to save image to mysql using android apps, and i found a java code , but i don't have appropiate php script that allows that