# PHPMailer: Could not access file for Website Contact Form

Tags: php, html

I have found similar topics but I'm bad at PHP and don't know how handle files.
Im programming a Contact Form for my website, the text gets sent but I can't get the attachment to work. I get the error "Could not access file". I probably have to first upload the attachment to the server, right?
This is my contact form in html.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 " id="form_container">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2> 
                <p> Please send your message below. We will get back to you at the earliest! </p>
                <form action="mailer.php" role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <label for="message"> Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Your Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Image Upload:</label>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Browse</button>
                                    <input type="file" name="image" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right" >Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
                <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Posted your message successfully!</h3> </div>
                <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
include "phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
include "smtp.php";
include "exception.php";

   $msj= 'Name ' . $_POST["name"] . ' ' .'Nummer ' . $_POST["nummer"] . ' ' . 'Kilometer ' . $_POST["kilometer"];
   $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
   //authentication SMTP enabled
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
   $mail->Host = "smtp.switchplus-mail.ch";
   //indico el puerto que usa Gmail 465 or 587
   $mail->Port = 465; 
   $mail->Username = "ankauf@7717.ch";
   $mail->Password = "xxx";
   $mail->SetFrom("ankauf@7717.ch","Ankaufs Formular");
   $mail->AddReplyTo("ankauf@7717.ch","ankauf@7717.ch");
   $mail->Subject = "Auto Ankaufs Offerte";
   $mail->MsgHTML($msj);
   $mail->AddAddress("handel@audi-bmw-mercedes.ch");
   $mail->AddAttachment($_POST["image"]);




if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message has been sent";
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to use `$_FILES` and adding the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the form to access the image's details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send image to php script using Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962756/send-image-to-php-script-using-form)

Comment: _"I probably have to first upload the attachment to the server, right?"_ - Yes. If you don't upload it, there's no way for PHP to use it in any way since PHP only runs on the server. [Here's the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) about handling file uploads in PHP